# Running a shell script in subdirectory

Tags: bash, shell, cd

I am running shell script from another folder in current directory as follows, where I am taking the file.txt, creating a folder as file basename and moving that file to the directory file and then running the subsequent scripts on file.txt in file directory:

```
 ../anotherfolder/myscript.sh file.txt
```

The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=${1}
filename=$(basename "$file")
filename="${filename%.*}"
mkdir $filename
cd $filename
......rest of the shell scripts to be executed in the subdirectory
```

I would like to execute the rest of the shell scripts (after cd $filename) , in the subdirectory $filename, what would be the best way to do so?

Comment: Why do you think it's not executing the rest of the script in the subdirectory?

Comment: I know that 'cd' command is 'temporary' in shell script and the script reverts back to the directory in which the script is executed.

Comment: It only reverts when the script ends. The rest of the commands in the script will be executed in the subdirectory.

Comment: Oh thanks for this info, i will verify my script in that case

Comment: The directory will also end whenever the subshell running the `cd` exits.  This doesn't occur in your case (there is no subshell), but is something to be aware of.  That is in: `cmd1; (cd $foo; cmd2; cmd3; ) cmd4;` only two commands are executed in the directory $foo, while cmd1 and cmd4 are executed in the original working directory.

Comment: btw, you really should use `mkdir "$filename"` and `cd "$filename" || exit`. Quotes make sure the name works even if has spaces; the `|| exit` makes sure you don't run the rest of your script if the `cd` fails (and thus run a bunch of code in the wrong directory). These are both hints that http://shellcheck.net/ will provide, by the way.

Comment: (btw, don't think of `cd` in a script being temporary -- it's as permanent as any other invocation of `cd`: It applies *for as long as that process continues to be in memory*. Thus, you run `cd` in an interactive shell, it applies until that shell exits; it's the same in a script: You run `cd` in a shell in a script, it applies until that shell exits -- which happens when the script ends, if (as is usual) you have a separate shell instance executing that script).